# Question about limit points

Tags: general-topology

The reference I'm using defined a limit point of a set as:

**Definition.** A point $x$ is a *limit point* of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ in some point other than $x$.

This kind of looks awkward and confusing to me in ways that I can't exactly explain. I want to know if I can restate the same thing using the definition:

**Definition.** A point $x$ is a *limit point* of a set $A$ if for every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ we have $$(V_{\epsilon}(x)\setminus\{x\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset.$$

Does this make sense? I also understand that with this *redefinition* of some sorts, $A$ should not be the empty set.

Comment: This is fine.  Its just a more formal statement of the given definition.

Comment: Thanks then. It was worded quite awkwardly that I feared that the limit point that I had in mind is different from what the book is trying to describe.